# configure dflags for dependency in dub

Tags: d, dub

I have a library that contains code compiled with dflags -fPIC. The library is a static one but get's linked into a (c++) shared library. So I need the -fPIC flag.
I can add the dflags to dub.json, but I add a dependency to a different library, the dependency gets compiled without -fPIC. Is it possible to pass the -fPIC flag on to the other library?

Comment: you could compile the dependency and add it to libs

Comment: Try to to put: "dflags": ["-fPIC"] in dub.json